# Não consigo alterar o título da ActionBar (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android-studio, actionbar

Fala pessoal blz, não estou conseguindo alterar o título da ActioBar de um app que fiz no Android Studio. Fiz exatamente como o professor do meu curso online ensinou(Criando um projeto sem Activity). O que é engraçado, é que quando eu refiz o app, dessa vez usando uma "Empty Activity", eu consegui alterar o título. Outro detalhe é que ele também não reconhece a Activity principal como LAUNCHER, e é preciso especificar no emulador para ele abrir. Vejam o código Java:

```
package com.fernando.agenda.ui.activity;
```

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.fernando.agenda.R;
import com.fernando.agenda.dao.AlunoDAO;
import com.fernando.agenda.modelo.Aluno;

public class FormularioAlunoActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

```
public static final String TITULO_APPBAR = "queriatrocar";
private EditText campoNome;
private EditText campoTelefone;
private EditText campoemail;
final AlunoDAO dao = new AlunoDAO();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_formulario_aluno);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(TITULO_APPBAR);
    inicializacaoDosCampos();
    configuraBotaoSalvar();
}


private void configuraBotaoSalvar() {
    Button botaosalvar = findViewById(R.id.activity_formulario_aluno_botao_salvar);
    botaosalvar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Aluno alunoCriado = criaAluno();
            salva(alunoCriado);

        }
    });
}

private void inicializacaoDosCampos() {
    campoNome = findViewById(R.id.activity_formulario_aluno_nome);
    campoTelefone = findViewById(R.id.activity_formulario_aluno_telefone);
    campoemail = findViewById(R.id.activity_formulario_aluno_email);
}

private void salva(Aluno aluno) {
    dao.salva(aluno);

    finish();
}

@NonNull
private Aluno criaAluno() {
    String nome = campoNome.getText().toString();
    String telefone = campoTelefone.getText().toString();
    String email = campoemail.getText().toString();

    Aluno alunoCriado = new Aluno(nome, telefone, email);
    return alunoCriado;
}
```

}

O arquivo Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".ui.activity.FormularioAlunoActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".ui.activity.ListaAlunoActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

E o arquivo Strings:

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">queriatrocar</string>
```

Apesar te tudo isso, a barra aparece com o título "Agenda"(que é o nome do projeto), ao invés de aparecer "queriatrocar". A mesma coisa se tentar na Activity "ListaAlunoActivity". Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

```js
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        myToolbar.setTitle("Seu Titulo");
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    }
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).